# Order query only by a specific field if all values from result set are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am building a custom document versioning system in my website.

For this, I have 2 tables "`vrm_document`" and "`vrm_document_active_document`".
The first table contains all documents on my website, while the second table tells me which document is the active version for which user, so the second table contains the `vrm_document_id` field and a `user_id` field. Active documents are indicated by the `parent_vrm_document_id` being not NULL.

I have 2 kinds of documents:

- Default documents
- Documents uploaded by the users themselves

Each document that is uploaded contains versions, and min. 1 and max. 1 version has to be active at all times for the user. Thus the second table `vrm_document_active_document` will always contain the `vrm_document_id` combined with the `user_id` for the documents uploaded by the user himself.

However, the problem resides in the fact that default documents are documents that are provided by my website and will always be available to everyone. When a user does not have its own version of a default document, the default document will become the active version for that user by default. This is implicated. For active documents we do NOT insert rows in the `vrm_document_active_document` table. This means that if there are no versions of a default document active for the user, the default document becomes the active version by default for that user.

When displaying the documents with their versions to the user, I want to show all the versions in a list under each other, where the active version is displayed first, and then the others are sorted on the last modified time.

The following query gives me the correct results for documents that aren't default documents:

```
SELECT vd.*
FROM `vrm_document` AS `vd`
LEFT JOIN vrm_document_active_document AS vdad ON (vd.vrm_document_id = vdad.vrm_document_id AND vd.user_id = vdad.user_id)
WHERE ((`vd`.`parent_vrm_document_id` = 1 AND `vd`.`user_id` IN (2,18,21)) OR (`vd`.`vrm_document_id` = 1  ) ) 
ORDER BY vdad.vrm_document_id DESC, vd.timestamp_modified_utc DESC
```

However, as can be seen from the query, if we imagine that document ID 1 to be a default document, all fields in the `vrm_document_active_document` table will contain NULL, and thus it will sort based on the modified time.

The following is (in pseudo-code) what I need to achieve, is this possible using mariaDB SQL?

ORDER BY:

- if all values == NULL then value with default_document is first , then order by modified_utc
- else order by modified_utc

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/71TUvdxFgFLhdncgo4BRre/1

EDIT: DB Fiddle added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB you have the [ifnull](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ifnull/) function and you can use it as

```
ifnull(expr1, expr2)
```

which effectively says:

evaluate expr1 and if it's null, then evaluate expr2

If I understand your problem well, then your solution looks like

```
order by ifnull(vdad.vrm_document_id, ifnull(vd.timestamp_modified_utc, someothervalue)) desc
```

In the clause above someothervalue represents any field that you may want to default to. The desirable criteria was unclear to me. However, if you want the default document to be the very first criteria, then

```
ORDER BY dv.is_default_document desc, vdad.vrm_document_id DESC, vd.timestamp_modified_utc DESC
```

or, if you want that to be the very last criteria, then

```
ORDER BY vdad.vrm_document_id DESC, vd.timestamp_modified_utc DESC, dv.is_default_document desc
```

EDIT

```
SELECT vdad.*, vd.*
FROM `vrm_document` AS `vd`
LEFT JOIN vrm_document_active_document AS vdad ON (vd.vrm_document_id = vdad.vrm_document_id AND vd.user_id = vdad.user_id)
WHERE ((`vd`.`parent_vrm_document_id` = 1 AND `vd`.`user_id` IN (2,18,21)) OR (`vd`.`vrm_document_id` = 1  ) ) 
ORDER BY 
CASE not exists (
    SELECT 1 as cnt
    FROM `vrm_document` AS `vd2`
    LEFT JOIN vrm_document_active_document AS vdad2 ON (vd2.vrm_document_id = vdad2.vrm_document_id AND vd2.user_id = vdad2.user_id)
    WHERE ((`vd2`.`parent_vrm_document_id` = 1 AND `vd2`.`user_id` IN (2,18,21)) OR (`vd2`.`vrm_document_id` = 1  ) ) 
    AND not ((vdad2.vrm_document_id is null) AND (vdad2.user_id))
)
WHEN 1 THEN vd.vrm_document_id
ELSE 0 END,
vdad.vrm_document_id DESC, 
vd.timestamp_modified_utc DESC
```

The query above uses case-when-else-end to check for the existence of some records. It is unclear for me what should be the exact criteria, but, even if the example above is not your exact match, then you can replace

```
AND not ((vdad2.vrm_document_id is null) AND (vdad2.user_id))
```

to what you need and it should work.

EDIT2

The current query sorts by the two criteria in the question by default, but if the first two columns are null, then the very first element will be the default document:

```
SELECT vdad.*, vd.*
FROM `vrm_document` AS `vd`
LEFT JOIN vrm_document_active_document AS vdad ON (vd.vrm_document_id = vdad.vrm_document_id AND vd.user_id = vdad.user_id)
WHERE ((`vd`.`parent_vrm_document_id` = 1 AND `vd`.`user_id` IN (2,18,21)) OR (`vd`.`vrm_document_id` = 1  ) ) 
ORDER BY 
CASE not exists (
    SELECT 1 as cnt
    FROM `vrm_document` AS `vd2`
    LEFT JOIN vrm_document_active_document AS vdad2 ON (vd2.vrm_document_id = vdad2.vrm_document_id AND vd2.user_id = vdad2.user_id)
    WHERE ((`vd2`.`parent_vrm_document_id` = 1 AND `vd2`.`user_id` IN (2,18,21)) OR (`vd2`.`vrm_document_id` = 1  ) ) 
    AND not ((vdad2.vrm_document_id is null) AND (vdad2.user_id))
)
WHEN 1 THEN vd.is_default_document
ELSE 0 END desc,
vdad.vrm_document_id DESC, 
vd.timestamp_modified_utc DESC
```

Comment: Hello Lajos, thanks for your comment! I was not aware of the ifnull operator. 
The problem I have is that if you see at the DBFiddle, the first two columns are NULL for both of them. In this case (and only in the case if the first two fields are NULL for EVERY single row in the result set) I want to order them based on the default_document field before ordering on the last modified time, if at least one row is not NULL, then the ordering of the default_document field has to be gone, and we only need to order on the last modified time.

Comment: @Dennis now I understand that if the first two columns are null for all records, then one ordering should apply (I picked vd.vrm_document_id, but I don't know if that's your expectation), otherwise I use the same value for all records (0), so, if the criteria was not true, then the second and third ordering would apply.

Comment: That query looks complex! I tried it and it's so close to the solution. I have updated the DB fiddle to include the query you suggested. It does indeed put the default document at first position now! However, the rest of the results are not sorted correctly on the modified_utc time. Row 2 and 3 should be in different order in the example provided. Thank you so much already for the effort!

Comment: @Dennis now I think I finally understand what the expectation is. If I'm not mistaken, you intend to use the two sorts in your question by default, but if the first two columns are null for every record, then you prefer to put the default document as the very first record. Updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: That is exactly what i needed! It's exactly as i need it to be, thank you very very much !